# Mongoose: how to use aggregate and find together

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

How can I use [aggregate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-Aggregate) and `find` together in Mongoose?
i.e I have the following schema:

```
const schema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  name: { type: String, default: 'development' }
  followers: [{ type: Mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users'}]
...
})

export default Mongoose.model('Locations', schema)
```

How can I query the users with only the fields `name` and `followers_count`.
`followers_count`:  the length of `followers` .

There, I know we can use [select](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) to get only the field `name`.
How can we get the count of `followers`?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

For MongoDB 3.6 and greater, use the **[`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)** operator which allows the use of aggregation expressions within the query language:

```
var followers_count = 30;
db.locations.find({
   "$expr": { 
       "$and": [
           { "$eq": ["$name", "development"] },
           { "$gte": [{ "$size": "$followers" }, followers_count ]}
       ]
    }
});
```

---

For non-compatible versions, you can use both the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** and **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** pipelines to query your collection. For example, if you want to query the `locations` collection where the name is 'development' and `followers_count` is greater than 30, run the following aggregate operation:

```
const followers_count = 30;
Locations.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": "development" } },
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$gte": [ { "$size": "$followers" }, followers_count ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
]).exec((err, locations) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(locations);
})
```

or within a single pipeline as

```
Locations.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$and": [
                        { "$eq": ["$name", "development"] },
                        { "$gte": [ { "$size": "$followers" }, followers_count ] }
                     ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
]).exec((err, locations) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(locations);
})
```

The above will return the locations with just the `_id` references from the users. To return the users documents as means to "populate" the followers array, you can then append the **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** pipeline.

---

If the underlying Mongo server version is 3.4 and newer, you can run the pipeline as

```
let followers_count = 30;
Locations.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": "development" } },
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$gte": [ { "$size": "$followers" }, followers_count ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "followers",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "followers"
        }
    }
]).exec((err, locations) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(locations);
})
```

else you would need to **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** the followers array before applying **[`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup)** and then regroup with **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline after that:

```
let followers_count = 30;
Locations.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": "development" } },
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$gte": [ { "$size": "$followers" }, followers_count ] },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$followers" },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "followers",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "follower"
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$follower" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "created": { "$first": "$created" },
            "name": { "$first": "$name" },
            "followers": { "$push": "$follower" }
        }
    }
]).exec((err, locations) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(locations);
})
```

Answer (score 25):

You can use as the following:

```
db.locations.aggregate([
  {$match:{"your find query"}},
  {$project:{"your desired fields"}}
])
```

In the match you can do stuff like:

```
{{$match:{name:"whatever"}}
```

In the project, you can select the fields you want using numbers 0 or 1 like:

```
{$project:{_id:1,created:0,name:1}}
```

Which 0 means, do not put and 1 means put.